# Disabling Cloudwatch for autoscaled EC2s - is it disabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I occasionally need to launch some EC2s and it was becoming harder and harder to manually find available Spot instances, so I started using Auto Scaling: https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/

The problem is that on this page: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/autoscaling/faqs/
It says:

> Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling Auto Scaling is enabled by Amazon CloudWatch
> and carries no additional fees. Each instance launched by Auto Scaling
> is automatically enabled for monitoring and the applicable Amazon
> Cloudwatch charges will be applied.

Is there a way of avoiding Cloudwatch fees when using Auto Scaling? disabling it and checking that the bill stays $0 isn't possible, since there's also other services using it.

I am using a Auto Scaling Group with a Launch Template. The Launch Template says:

```
Detailed CloudWatch monitoring
-
```

Is this okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enable or turn off detailed monitoring for your instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-cloudwatch-new.html)

> By default, your instance is enabled for basic monitoring. You can optionally enable detailed monitoring.

> The number of metrics sent by an EC2 instance as part of EC2 Detailed Monitoring is dependent on the instance type.

[Detailed CloudWathc Monitoring](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/)

Plus the free tier is decent enough you might need end up too much cost depending on your instances type and it is recommended to ensure accuracy, that you enable detailed monitoring.

```
- Basic Monitoring Metrics (at 5-minute frequency)

- 10 Detailed Monitoring Metrics (at 1-minute frequency)

- 1 Million API requests (not applicable to GetMetricData and GetMetricWidgetImage)
```

Comment: Thanks, Sam. If I look under an instance in the EC2 console -> Monitoring tab, I can see detailed monitoring is off. Guess that's the minimum I can pay.

Answer (score 1):

Yes don't use the detail monitoring as that is in 60 second granularity instead of the 5 minutes.

From experience  the Cloudwatch fees (if any) would not cost that much. Something like a few cents per month is what i tend to see

Comment: I'm not sure how much my gig is costing the company since we already had varying workloads before my instances. Tyvm.